# How to perform a partial match query in ElasticSearch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I have been trying to perform a partial match query in ElasticSearch but haven't been successful yet (despite my attempts to follow instructions on similar questions here in SO).

I have an index with 5 fields:

```
author_name, title, content, chapter_name, email
```

Ideally, I would like to search for a term and have it find results as long as it partially matches any of these fields.

For the following data:

```
{
  "author_name": "John Doe",
  "title": "A Nice Summer",
  "content": "It was a nice summer back in 1969",
  "chapter_name": "The 60s",
  "email": "johndoe@email.com"
 }
```

I should get it if I query for `Doe`, `1969`, `60s`, `it was`

(Note the space in the last term. I have been having issues with spaces as well)

Maybe I am just using the wrong elements in building my query

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same question, these pages in the official ElasticSearch documentation explain quite well how to achieve this:

[Ngrams for Partial Matching](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_ngrams_for_partial_matching.html)

That page links to the following page, which gives a great example of how to achieve what you want:

[Ngrams for Compound Words](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/ngrams-compound-words.html)

These links are both part of the following chapter in the ES documentation:

[Partial Matching](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-matching.html)